# Office 365 Offline installer package

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013, office365

I have a license to install Office 365 (Home Premium) on multiple computers. Unfortunately, all I can download on the Office website is a 550KiB net-installer, i.e. one that downloads the complete package from the web and installs it right away without asking too many questions.

Now, doing this *once* is okay, although it’s a huge annoyance because my internet connection at home is really slow. However when thinking about doing that again for the next machine, I kind of don’t even want to upgrade at all… What’s worse is that a failed update today apparently bricked my installation, so I spent the last few hours waiting for my computer to download it again to reinstall it.

So, is there some download-once offline installer for Office 365? Or can I just use a Office 2013 (Professional) ISO and install that instead and then just activate it using my Microsoft account?

Another thing that is somewhat related is that the net-installer asks no questions at all, so I always get the full package with whatever default options there are. For my notebook, given its limited SSD disk space, I would rather configure this a bit, for example exclude Access and Publisher (I use these very rarely). Is this somehow possible?

Comment: I would just copy the installer files that installer package downloads to the computer.

Comment: Note that you may have to create or modify an .xml file in the working directory to get it to install correctly from offline.

Answer (score 3):

You can get Office 2013 32 or 64-bit from [here](http://www.heidoc.net/joomla/technology-science/microsoft/73-office-2013-direct-download-links).

As Brad said above after installing one of the above you can activate using your Microsoft Account.

Comment: Those weren't direct download links; they were being routed via some site that was no doubt keeping tabs on who was downloading what. I've linked to a much better page instead that contains links from MS/DigitalRiver.

Comment: hey I didn't realize that Karan. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

it is also possible to download an image (.img) file for offline installation on [office.com/myaccount](http://www.office.com/myaccount).

- Just open the link
- Click on `Install`
- Click on `Language and install options`
- Click on `Additional install options`
- With the link `Download offline installer` you will be able to download an image file for both x32 and x64 Microsoft Office

Answer (score 0):

I installed Office 2013 Pro the other day from my MSDN subscription. It was a full ISO download. After it installed I started up Excel and the main prompt asked me for an email address to authenticate the product with. Below that was a link to use a traditional product key. Since I had a key from MSDN I used that option. My guess at the time was that if I had an Office 365 subscription I could authenticate with the associated email adresss.

If you have access to a full installer I would recommend giving that a try.

Comment: This fails to answer the question. He obviously *doesn't* have the full offline installer and wants to know where he can get that from, or whether his Office 365 Home Premium license will work with a Pro ISO.

Answer (score -1):

You can download an iso file from the official [Microsoft 365](https://account.microsoft.com/services/microsoft365/details#billing) website.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).